# Performing calculations on data in one column and moving result to another in Excel.

Tags: vba, excel, vectorization

This is my first time using VBA, so I'm not good with the syntax of excel VBA at all (I previously learned c++ and matlab).

I am trying to take a column of data, do some simple calculations (like multiply by 3), and put it in a new column.

Now the data I'm trying to sort have duplicates in them. For instance, this column has:

```
1  
2  
3  
4

2  
3  
6   
8    
9  
2  
3
```

Repeating numbers and sometimes a blank in them. Right now I'm not too worried about sorting. I'm have trouble just taking a bunch of arrays from one column, and put a different set of arrays in the next column. How do I do this? The code below works for strings, how do I tweak this? Thanks!

Here's my attempt:

```
Sub unique()
    Dim arr As New Collection, a
    Dim aFirstArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    aFirstArray() = Range("E:E")
    ' On Error Resume Next
    For Each a In aFirstArray
        arr.Add a, Str(a)
        'I tried changing Str(a) to Integer(a), apparently it doesn't work like this in Excel
    Next

    For i = 1 To arr.Count
        Cells(i, 3) = arr(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be in exact line with your thought process, but I think the essence is there, using some different VBA tools. Let me know if you have questions or if it doesn't solve your problem.

This code ignores duplicates and blank cells. It should be pretty easy to adjust if you want to keep those in your lists.

```
Sub unique()

Dim i As Integer
Dim dict As New Dictionary
Dim cel As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A12")

i = 1
For Each cel In rng
    If cel <> vbNullString Then
        If Not dict.Exists(cel.Value) Then
            dict.Add cel.Value, i
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
Next

For i = 1 To dict.Count - 1
    Cells(i, 3) = dict.Keys(i)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, those codes works great, I made some tweaks and it's exactly what I needed. Now I am trying to figure out how to perform some operations on these columns of data. 
For instance, I have various operations, in random order (Op 100, Op 200, Op 300, 100, 300 etc) for column A, and column B has the corresponding time data for those operations, and I'm trying to find the difference of time values between operations(Op 200 - Op 200 time, for instance)

Essentially, my question is how do I loop through column A while performing an operation on column B on corresponding rows?

Comment: Because you are new to StackOverflow you may not fully understand how it best works - for the most benefit for all who use it. Since your original question was answered satisfactorily, please mark it as such. This helps users who search in the future to have confidence in the Answer. With regards to your question in the above  comment. Please post another question. If you want to let me know you did that, I would be happy to address that question when it's posted. This too helps keep things specific and simple, so in the future, users can find answers to specific Q's.